# c# List using where statement

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc-3, filtering

My application is asp.net MVC using Linq-to-Sql. I am trying to use the following to filter a view.

I have already added the filter to my SQL Server view using:

```
WHERE (dbo.Client.Recstatus IS NULL) OR (dbo.Client.Recstatus = 0)
```

It works well when I run it in SQL Server Management Studio, however I still see the entries in my application.

I tried to filter it again in my repository using:

```
List<vw_Client_info> searchResult = new List<vw_Client_info>().Where(c=> c.Recstatus != 1);
```

`Recstatus` is `smallint`

I get the following error:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

I would appreciate your assistance, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you forget to use the `ToList()` method at the end. Try this:

```
List<vw_Client_info> searchResult = 
    new List<vw_Client_info>().Where(c=> c.Recstatus != 1).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Hossein, I don't get the error.  Any idea why if I have filtered my view in Sql, the data still show!  Thanks again.

Comment: @user373721 not sure if I understood your comment.

Comment: I am trying to figure out, if I have the filters in the sql view, and when I run it; it removes all entries that are equl to 1.  However in my table in MVC, these enteries that are equal to 1 still showing.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

two problems

1. `new List<vw_Client_info>()` is new list there is no data
2. you have to call `.ToList()` at the end of the statement

You can try something like below

```
using (YourDatacontext context= new YourDatacontext(connStr))
{
    List<vw_Client_info> searchResult = 
          context.vw_Client_infos.Where(c=> c.Recstatus != 1).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Thank you all for your kind and quick support

Answer (score 0):

Enumerable methods inlcuding `Where` do not return a List but rather they return a IEnumerable

so you could modify your code to

```
IEnumerable<vw_Client_info> searchResult = 
          new List<vw_Client_info>().Where(c=> c.Recstatus != 1);
```

Or

```
var searchResult = 
         new List<vw_Client_info>().Where(c=> c.Recstatus != 1);
```

which is same as above(compiler derives the type for you)

Or

```
List<vw_Client_info> searchResult = 
         new List<vw_Client_info>().Where(c=> c.Recstatus != 1).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are returning an anonymous type from your Select and you are trying to store it in the `List<vw_Client_info>`. The projections always create anonymous types.
so that u shd store in `IEnumerable` or use `ToList()` at tail.